# How can I remove noise from this picture?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i have applied some  filters to this image but it's always very noisy how can i remove noise and leave only the characters ?
here is my code :

```
import cv2    
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('12.jpg',0)    
img1=cv2.pyrDown(img)    
im=cv2.pyrDown(img1)    
final = cv2.medianBlur(im,5)    
cv2.imshow('image',final)    
cv2.waitKey(0)    
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(final,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)    
cv2.imshow('image1',th2)    
cv2.waitKey(0)    
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(im,cv2.CV_64F)    
cv2.imshow('image2',laplacian)    
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

original image:

[image: original image]

[image: image 1]

[image: image2]

Comment: “Some filters”. Please share what you have tried. It’s a lot easier looking for a solution if we don’t try to repeat your failed attempts. Posting your code will certainly help you to get an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I have something to get you started. You can incorporate the concept of [difference of Gaussians (DoG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians).

Here you perform Gaussian blur on an image with two different kernel sizes and subtract the resultants of the two. This method highlights the edges and is used in edge detection.

*Note:* Keep in mind this is just to get you started. You will have to tweak the parameters of the filters to get better results.

**Code:**

```
import cv2    
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\text.jpg',0)    
img1 = cv2.pyrDown(img)
img1 = cv2.medianBlur(img1, 11)

b1 = 69
b2 = 39
g1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img1, (b1, b1), 0) 
g2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img1, (b2, b2), 0)  
cv2.imshow('DoG', g1 - g2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result:**

[image]